Create type with same layout and niches but no Drop impl
I ran into the following issue today:
use std::mem::{size_of, MaybeUninit};

struct Foo<'a> {
    foo: &'a i32,
}


fn main() {
    println!("{}", size_of::<Option<Foo>>());              // 8
    println!("{}", size_of::<Option<MaybeUninit<Foo>>>()); // 16 (!)
}

So despite being #[repr(transparent)], MaybeUninit can have 'side effects' regarding
type layout because it apparently inhibits niche optimizations.
Is there a way for me to create a type let's say PhantomSlot<T> that does not have this problem?
I need a type that

can be constructed uninitialized (unlike e.g. ManuallyDrop)
has the same size, align and niches as T
never implements Drop regardless of T


This is the whole point of MaybeUninit. You are looking for ManuallyDrop.

You didn't tell us what you need this for, so I cannot be sure, but try putting the Option inside the MaybeUninit.

@ChayimFriedman: Thanks for the very fast answer and suggestions! This is part of a data structure implementation where the Foo is actually a generic T, so I can't use an intrusive Option. But thanks to your answer I figured out a solution. For my specific usecase I can just use a wrapper around ManuallyDrop that implements Default, but panics if it is actually called (which won't happen, I essentially needed a spacer).

It sounds a lot like you are trying to express in the type system what should be expressed in control flow. If you can cope with never actually using the uninitialized variant (either as uninitialized or as Default::default()), that means you don't need MaybeUninit nor Default. What you need is letting the compiler know that you never enter a state where your type is uninitialized. Depending on your control flow, there might be several ways to achieve that, some similar to your approach (e.g. panicking to inform the compiler of an impossible control flow path),...

...but are more semantically accurate, and therefore should be preferred (if they don't complicate the code much, which they shouldn't).

It's called ManuallyDrop, but it does not allow uninitialized memory:

ManuallyDrop<T> is guaranteed to have the same layout and bit validity as T, and is subject to the same layout optimizations as T.

use std::mem::{size_of, ManuallyDrop};

struct Foo<'a> {
    foo: &'a i32,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", size_of::<Option<Foo>>());              // 8
    println!("{}", size_of::<Option<ManuallyDrop<Foo>>>()); // 8
}

Your wanted type is fundamentally impossible. Consider:
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

fn main() {
    let mut v = Some(MaybeUninit::<&i32>::uninit());
    if let Some(v) = &mut v {
        unsafe {
            std::ptr::write_bytes(v.as_mut_ptr(), 0x00, 1);
        }
    }
}

0x00 is the discriminant of None. If Option<MaybeUninit<&i32>> was niche-optimized, this code would overwrite the discriminant, making the containing Option into None! Worse, we are borrowing the enum payload (which don't exist with None), so we invalidated our reference!
Even worse, uninitialized memory can have any bit pattern, including 0x00, so Some(MaybeUninit::uninit()) can be None! Even worse, uninitialized memory can have a variable bit pattern in different accesses, so if the compiler decided to compile code that checks the discriminant of the Option and does something based on it for some reason to two loads, they could differ, leading to arbitrary miscompilations!
